# Laravel 4 logout issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

The code I'm going to show is from a tutorial that I'm following.
The problem is: *that when I use a link to logout it redirects to the logout page which doesn't exist with the error 'Oops something went wrong' instead of to the index page.*

So the code working perfect it will logout, but why it redirect to logout page instead of index page?

Route of logout :

```
 Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
        /* 
        signout
        */
   Route::get('logout',array(
      'as'=>'logout-cont',
      'uses'=>'AccountController@getLogout'
    ));

});
```

Account controller getLogout:

```
public function getLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::route('index');
}
```

And my logout button:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    <li><a href="{{ URL::route('logout-cont') }}">logout</a></li>
@else
    <li><a href="{{ URL::route('login') }}">login</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ URL::route('create') }}">register</a></li>
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

From your problem I notice your debug mode is off. First go to `/app/config/app.php` and set `debug` to `true.

The following route should redirect you to your application's homepage:

```
return Redirect::to("/");
```

In your example you were redirecting to a route named 'index'. If you would like to use your approach make sure you have set up a route called `index` will point to the method in your controller that loads your preferred page!

Comment: I have route called index,anyway with your code it's not work too, its keep redirect to : E.G: http://localhost/netves/logout

Comment: Can you verify that the `getLogout()` is called and maybe post some more code from your router and maybe controller.

Comment: Please set `debug` to `true` in `/app/config/app.php`, so you will get a more meaningfull error message.

Answer (score 0):

Use following step AccountController.php

```
public function logout() {

    if (Auth::check()) {
        Session::flush();
        return Redirect::route('account-create');
    } else {
        return Redirect::route('account-create');
    }
}
```

then

```
Route::get('logout', array('as'=>'logout', 'uses'=>'AccountController@logout'));
```

route.php

```
<a href="{{URL::to('logout')}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Logout</a>
```

use navigation.php

note the filter.php

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});
```